Redirecting apex domain to non apex URL (www to non www) on GCP / GKE
There's an SEO issue where we have duplicate domains ..
For example - www.domain.com and domain.com.
I would like to recreate a 301 redirect from the apex website (www.domain.com) to the non-apex URL (domain.com)
Our UI application is hosted on GCP/GKE. I have found annotations for nginx type ingress to create such redirect .. but in our case, we're using GCP native ingress instead.
Any help or documentation will be highly appreciated. Nothing I found currently suits my needs.

I think this documentation will help you in this case.
(https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-global-traffic-mgmt#configure_a_url_redirect)

Thanks. I was able to set the reroute by deleting the apex domain from the ingress and by configuring url-map from the given documentation.. Some additional configuration was needed. I'll provide more information in the original post. –

I was able to configure the apex to non apex redirect using the following YAML configuration
   defaultService: global/backendServices/<YOUR-BACKEND-SERVICE-NAME> # Non apex load balancer backend
   name: global-lb-map
   hostRules:
   - hosts:
     - 'www.domain.co.il'
     pathMatcher: www-matcher
   pathMatchers:
   - defaultService: global/backendServices/<YOUR-BACKEND-SERVICE-NAME>
     name: www-matcher
     routeRules:
       - matchRules:
           - prefixMatch: /
         priority: 1
         urlRedirect:
           hostRedirect: "domain.co.il"
           redirectResponseCode: MOVED_PERMANENTLY_DEFAULT
           stripQuery: True

Saving the file as redirect.yaml, and then apply using gcloud compute url-maps import global-lb-map --source .\redirect.yaml --global
'target-https-proxies' and 'forwarding-rules' resources have to be configured aswell.
the following commands may be used
target-https-proxies

Ceate an SSL certificate or use the one already attached to your apex domain

gcloud compute target-https-proxies create https-proxy \
    --url-map=global-lb-map \
    --ssl-certificates=ssl-cert \
    --global

forwarding-rules

Create a static IP first.

gcloud compute forwarding-rules create https-forwarding-rule \
    --address=[YOUR_GLOBAL_STATIC_IP_ADDRESS_NAME] \
    --global \
    --target-https-proxy=https-proxy \
    --ports=443

When all 3 have been configured, make sure you remove the apex domain from your ingress configuration field and create an A type DNS record pointing the APEX to the newly created static IP that was assigned with your load balancer.
You will then be able to see the redirect succeed.

Thanks @JanMaroon for your help.
